# Pass an option syntax string as filename

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cat, command-line-arguments

I somehow got a file named --no-recursion in a directory. How can I get `cat` to show what it contains? Not like this, since the argument gets interpreted as an option:

```
root@nagini [/home/lalilulelo]# cat --no-recursion 
cat: unrecognized option `--no-recursion'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
root@nagini [/home/lalilulelo]# cat \--no-recursion 
cat: unrecognized option `--no-recursion'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
root@nagini [/home/lalilulelo]# cat \\--no-recursion 
cat: \--no-recursion: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that `cat` treats `--no-recursion` as its option. You can do either of the following:

```
cat ./--no-recursion
```

OR

```
cat -- --no-recursion
```

Can do the same thing with `rm` to delete this file (since it's probably an error of some kind).

In my first example, I prepended current directory path ("./") to the file name, so it does not start with an option prefix, and in my second example I added a special option `--`, which means "stop treating anything that comes after this as an option".